# Linux command to delete directory except specific directory fail in shell script of pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh, jenkins-groovy

At `/home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/test/` location, I've multiple directories. I want to delete all directories except `test1` which I achieve using following from terminal -

```
rm -rf /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/test/!("test1")
```

Same I want to achieve through Jenkins pipeline hence wrote method -

```
def cleanWorkspaceDir() {
    echo "Cleaning workspace"
    sh '''rm -rf /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/test/!("test1")
    '''
}
```

But it gives error - `/home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@tmp/durable-810bac2b/script.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token`('`

Could you please help how I can resolve this?

Comment: `def cleanWorkspaceDir() {` is not a valid command in POSIX shell.

Comment: See [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05) how to write a correct function definition.

Comment: That method is groovy method defined in Jenkins pipeline code.

Comment: So why do you then run it as shell script, and not as groovy program?

Comment: In groovy, I could not find a way to delete directories except specific directory in a directory, the way we've in linux.

Comment: Why don't you try `find /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/test/ -type f -not -name test1 -delete` instead of `rm -rf` ?

Comment: @hariK, manually I tried this but this does not delete any of the directories.

Comment: @TDHM It's strange. I tried that command manually and through jenkins and it works.

Comment: @TDHM : I don't object against writing it in shell instead of Groovy. I just wonder why you used Groovy-syntax (with `def ...`)  in your shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
def cleanWorkspaceDir() {
    echo "Cleaning workspace"
    sh '''find test/ -mindepth 1 '!' -name test1 -type d -exec rm -rf '{}' +
    '''
}

pipeline {
   agent { label 'slave' }

   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
            sh 'mkdir -p test/{a/{p,q},b,c/{r,s},test1,test2}'
            sh 'ls -lR'
            cleanWorkspaceDir()
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Replace `find` command above with any of the following:

```
find /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/test/ -mindepth 1 -type d -not -name test1 -delete

find /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/test/ -mindepth 1 ! -name 'test1' -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
```